# Python w/ Excel sheet. For each value in First Col. calculate two columns.

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I do have an excel sheet that has for example 100 rows in Col A the value changes after every five rows, so First 5 rows have value 1, Second 5 rows has value 2,.. etc until I reach the last 5 rows that have value 20. I want to go through Col A values and computes Col B with Col C. in ColA I will have 20 values.

[image]

So, a traditional way to do that is:

```
n= 5
lst=[row for row in range(1, 100//n) for _ in range(n)]
row=1
for row in lst:
   value = sheet.cell(row, 0).value
   if value==1:
    ''' My code here'''
   elif value == 2:
    ''' My code here'''

  ::
  ::
  ::
  ::
  ::
  ::
  ::
  ::
# I do this till I reach value == 20
```

I don't want to write more lots lines of code to go through all the values in Col A. All these lines doing the same job except they change the value in column A after every 5 rows.

My question here how can I make a loop or any other way to go through col A. Please if you want me to elaborate I'm happy to do so.

The output should be like this as an example:

```
For value # 1 in Col A. Total is: 50 (sum numbers in Col B with Col C)
For value # 2 in Col A. Total is: 86 (sum numbers in Col B with Col C)
For value # 3 in Col A. Total is: 99 (sum numbers in Col B with Col C)
...
Until Reach 
For value # 20 in Col A. Total is: 4235 (sum numbers in Col B with Col C)
```

> Note: How Can I make a loop in values in Col A. calculate values in Col B with Col C that corresponding to value in Col A.

Comment: I wish to comment on my question before downvote my question.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're asking, but enumerating the list will give you an index, a number that when divided by 5 gives you the value you seem to be looking for in column A.

```
for index, row in enumerate(lst):
   value = sheet.cell(row, 0).value
   columnA = int(float(index)/5)+1
```

No need to divide the list into 5 at the end.

Comment: Thank you @John my problem here I do have 1000 rows and 200 values in Col A. Each value has 5 rows. How to compute all the values in Col A in shorter way.

Comment: My answer addresses that. Not sure why it was downvoted. If this doesn't work for you, describe the new output and how it should be different.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. Also, I didn't know who downvote my Question. No one asked me to explain my question. My question here is that how to shorten my code in the if statement, I don't want to do it 200 times.

Comment: I explained it more. It has to be 200 values. you can see the output and how it should be.